# How can I feed a rational or irrational number to argparse?

Tags: python, terminal, argparse, rational-number

How can I feed rational numbers like 3/2, through terminal, into my python script using argparse? 
I have the same problem when I want to input pi or any other irrational numbers like sqrt(2) using argparse.

Regards,
Hadi

Comment: What have you tried so far? For a rational number you could pass in two arguments, a numerator and a denominator. For an irrational number you are out of luck because you could only pass in the closest representation as a floating point value - e.g. 3.151592654 etc. Unless you want to create an argument (-irrat for example) that has a specific set of enumerated definitions like 'pi' and 'root2' or something. But then when translating these internally you'll still end up with a floating point representation.

Answer (score 1):

With

```
import argparse
import sys
print(sys.argv)
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('aNumber')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args)
```

sample runs:

```
1414:~/mypy$ python3 stack53964076.py -h
['stack53964076.py', '-h']
usage: stack53964076.py [-h] aNumber

positional arguments:
  aNumber

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
1417:~/mypy$ python3 stack53964076.py 3/2
['stack53964076.py', '3/2']
Namespace(aNumber='3/2')
1417:~/mypy$ python3 stack53964076.py pi
['stack53964076.py', 'pi']
Namespace(aNumber='pi')
1417:~/mypy$ python3 stack53964076.py sqrt(2)
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
1417:~/mypy$ python3 stack53964076.py 'sqrt(2)'
['stack53964076.py', 'sqrt(2)']
Namespace(aNumber='sqrt(2)')
```

In all these cases `args.aNumber` will be a string.  In the last case I had to include quotes to prevent the shell from trying to parse the '(' itself.

Handling these strings is the responsibility of your own code, not `argparse`.